# Downscale image preserving tiny details

Tags: image, machine-learning, resize

Is there an algorithm that would allow to downscale image but preserve the little details like **tiny cracks** and **scratches**?

For example, let's say we have a photo 1024x1024 of banana on neutral background. And banana has some tiny cracks and some tiny dots of beginning of rotting.

Now if we downscale banana down to let's say 264x264 - we loose those tiny cracks and dots. Is there a way to downscale but preserve those tiny details?

Maybe some **smart algorithm that will detect density of the information in the image**? Like if we consider the image of banana - it's mostly has very little information - mostly it's a same smooth yellowish color on white background. And cracks and dots are like dense objects in such environment.

Maybe there's some smart algorithm that can detect that and preserve those small information-dense objects on the picture?

Comment: Add an example and show what resizer is in use.